# Balloon styling in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How to use this balloon styling:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

The second style is activated when I set following option:

```
    "chartCursor": {
        "cursorPosition": "mouse"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second styling is the so called [`drop`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon#drop). It is activated by a setting in the respective `balloon` configuration (located in the graph settings):

```
"balloon":{
    "drop":true
}
```

To deactivate the drop you can either set it to false or just delete it (default is false).

Comment: Yes that's it !